# Objective c, Memory Leak, reading from sqlite and assigning values to a NSDictionary and NSAarray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a list of shops in a ListController file.
I've setted up a sqlite db, in which i've stored 60 shops.
On the top of the list i have a search bar.

I've made a class called DataController, that is responsible to load and store db datas.

```
@interface DataController : NSObject {
 sqlite3 *database;
 NSArray *shops;    
 NSDictionary* dictionaryOfShops;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *dictionaryOfShops;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* shops;
-(void)initializeShops;
```

initializeShops method loads data from the db, and stores results into the 2 props in this way:

```
-(void)initializeShops{
    [dictionaryOfShops release];
    [shops release];

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];

    if (sqlite3_open(....))
    NSString *query = ....
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String],-1, &statement, nil) ==   SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

           int rId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
           char *rName = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);

           Shop* s  = [[Shop alloc] init];
           s.ID = rId;
           if(sName != nil) s.Name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:rName];

               NSString *shopID = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",s.ID];
           [dictionary setObject:s forKey:shopID];
           [shopID release];
           [s release];         
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    [query release];

    dictionaryOfShops = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];
    shops =    [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[dictionary allValues]];

    dictionary = nil;
    [dictionary release];

       //Sorting
       NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortedList =[self.shops sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    self.shops = sortedList; 
    [sort release];
}
```

The problem is that when user enters some text into the search 
bar, I change the value of the query (adding LIKE....) and then call the initializeShops method again. This second time makes 
so many leaks, (related to the Shop class properties) and 
leaks also a NSDictionary and a NSArray.

Before posting this to you I've tried different solutions, but 
at least this doesn't leaks anything the first time I call 
initilizeShops.

I accept any suggestion, since I'm really stuck 
on it.

MORE:

The really strange thing is memory management of my var dictionary and the 2 props shops and dictionaryOfShops. With this code

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
//add data to dictionary 
dictionaryOfShops = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];
shops =    [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[dictionary allValues]];
[dictionary release]
```

Considering that dictionaryOfShops and shops are two properties (nonatomic,retain) synthesized, how can I change value to them without leaks?

The very first time I pass through this method nothing gets leaked, from the second time it starts to leak so many objects (the contents of the collections).

Comment: Suggestion: don't use the sqlite C api yourself.  Use a wrapper:  http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/resources/sqlite

Comment: Try run the static analyzer (Build and Analyze in Xcode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the error.
In my class Shop, i realize i didn't implement the method

```
 -(void)dealloc
```

So when I release the old dictionary (to prepare for a new assignment), all the fields inside of it didn't get released.

Comment: If you created the string with [NSString stringWithUtf8String:] you got an autoreleased instance which you don't have to release yourself.

Comment: thank you @weichsel, I changed the answer (I've pasted another text...sorry)

Answer (score 2):

The first question is *Why not just use Core Data?*  It is very likely going to be faster, will require less code, and will be significantly easier to maintain over time.  To be blunt;  SQLite is deceptively hard.  Easy to get started, exceptionally difficult to get right.

In any case, the memory management of `dictionary` is wrong.  It only isn't crashing because you swapped the order of the nil assignment and release as kennyTM suggested.   I would suggest *not* creating an autoreleased dictionary.

Otherwise, the code as written seems pretty leakless at first glance.  So:

1. Can you provide some more code? 
   Anything interesting memory wise
   going on elsewhere?
2. Are you using threading at all (or
   NSOperationQueue)?
3. Have you run under the Leaks
   instrument and retrieved the
   backtraces of allocation of the
   specific objects being leaked?

Comment: CoreData seems to much for my needs; infact I only read data, never write or update. The only thread-like thing i use is the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol. I've updated my question with some more hints. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
dictionary = nil;
[dictionary release];
```

Please swap these 2 statements. In this form it means `[nil release]` which is a no-op.

Comment: Nope -- do that and it'll just crash since dictionary was autoreleased on creation.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Did not see the `autorelease`. 

But if you're going to `autorelease` it, you don't need another `release`.

Comment: This is exactly the strange part of it. I've updated my question.